# Linking rows in the main sheet to automatically created sheet

Tags: excel, ms-office

first of all I've read many topics but none has my solution.

I have a data of 4 columns and **N** Rows *(as N is unknown number)*.
Here is a sample:

[image: here is a sample]

When a new row entered I want it to automatically create new sheet has the name which is written in title column of that row *(for the first row, create sheet with name "M")*
also copy all data in row M to the new sheet

i know there is a way
`=<SheetName>!<cell>` but it isn't really helps if i have for example 1000 columns,
i have to create 1000 sheet then copy 1000 times!!

that's all, thanks in advance.
also feel free to use any methods (such as VBA).

Comment: May I ask why you want to create a sheet for each row of data? Creating hundreds or thousands of sheets does not sound like a good approach. What is the purpose of these sheets? You may only need one sheet to report on the data in your first sheet, where you can select a name or title and then use formulas that dynamically look up the data as required.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be messy especially if you end up with a lot of Data.  The code below will allow you to run a Macro that will quickly create sheets based on the data.  This macro will only work once but it does the job

```
Sub CopyRowsToSheet()
' Variables needed for the formula
Dim NofRows As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim iActive As Boolean

' Counting the number of Rows in the active sheet
With ActiveSheet
    NofRows = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   
' Cycling through the number of rows on the active sheet
' we have set i = 2 as there is a header on the first page.  If there is no header then set i = 1
    For i = 2 To NofRows
        ' Creating the new sheet
        Worksheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Row " & i
        ' Copy Data to new sheet
        .Rows(i).Copy Sheets("Row " & i).Range("A1:D1")

    Next i
    
    End With
End Sub
```

Apologies not 100% sure how to make this automatic but if I find a way i will add it here for you